# Am I doing multi core programming the right way here

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multicore

I want to have some daemon that finds images that I need to convert into web and thumb versions. I thought python could be useful here, but I'm not sure if I'm doing things right here. I want to convert 8 photos simultaneously, the queue of images to be converted can be very long. We have several cores on the server and spawning each convert in a new process should let the OS take use of the available cores and things will go faster, right? This is the key point here, to make a process from python that again calls imagemagick's convert script and hope that things go a bit faster than running one and one convert from the python main thread.

So far I only started testing. So here is my test code. It will create 20 tasks (which is to sleep between 1 and 5 seconds), and give those tasks to a pool that in total has 5 threads.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from subprocess import call
from random import randrange
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, tid, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tid = tid
        self.queue = queue
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            sec = self.queue.get()
            print "Thread %d sleeping for %d seconds\n\n" % (self.tid, sec)
            p = Process(target=work, args=(sec,))
            p.start()
            p.join()
            self.queue.task_done()

class WorkerPool:
    def __init__(self, num_workers):
        self.queue = Queue()
        for tid in range(num_workers):
            Worker(tid, self.queue)

    def add_task(self, sec):
        self.queue.put(sec)

    def complete_work(self):
        self.queue.join()

def work(sec):
    call(["sleep", str(sec)])

def main():
    seconds = [randrange(1, 5) for i in range(20)]
    pool = WorkerPool(5)
    for sec in seconds:
        pool.add_task(sec)
    pool.complete_work()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So I run this script on the server:

```
johanhar@mamadev:~$ python pythonprocesstest.py
```

And then I check my processes on the server:

```
johanhar@mamadev:~$ ps -fux
```

The result from `ps` looks wrong to me. To me it looks as if I have something happening under python but in one process, so it will only go slower the more converts (or sleep as in this test case) I have even if we have several cores on the server...

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
johanhar 24246  0.0  0.0  81688  1608 ?        S    13:44   0:00 sshd: johanhar@pts/28
johanhar 24247  0.0  0.0 108336  1832 pts/28   Ss   13:44   0:00  \_ -bash
johanhar 49753  0.6  0.0 530620  7512 pts/28   Sl+  15:14   0:00      \_ python pythonprocesstest.py
johanhar 49822  0.0  0.0 530620  6252 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          \_ python pythonprocesstest.py
johanhar 49824  0.0  0.0 100904   564 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          |   \_ sleep 4
johanhar 49823  0.0  0.0 530620  6256 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          \_ python pythonprocesstest.py
johanhar 49826  0.0  0.0 100904   564 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          |   \_ sleep 3
johanhar 49837  0.0  0.0 530620  6264 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          \_ python pythonprocesstest.py
johanhar 49838  0.0  0.0 100904   564 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          |   \_ sleep 3
johanhar 49846  0.0  0.0 530620  6264 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00          \_ python pythonprocesstest.py
johanhar 49847  0.0  0.0 100904   564 pts/28   S+   15:14   0:00              \_ sleep 3
```

So if you still don't get the problem or what I'm asking for. Is this approach what you could call "multi core programming"?

Comment: ps output is just shows that you have 1 parent root python process which forked 4 children. It does not mean that everything is running "inside" one process. The shown tree is just relationship parent-child. I don't know if there is a way to manually set affinity between CPU cores in python, so in this way we assume that OS takes care about the distribution of processes between cores. So it looks like it should be fine in your case.

Comment: I've found an interesting library which could help you track how the processes are distributed between you cores. Here it is - https://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Take a look at get_cpu_affinity() set_cpu_affinity() functionality. BTW, I'm still keeping suggest that it's better to let OS to decide how to distribute the cores between processes, but you can try to track how it's going in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will just let the OS take care of it, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misreading the `ps` output. I count 4 distinct Python instances, each which could, in principle, be allocated to its own core. Whether they actually do get their own core is one of the harder bits of multi-processing.

Yes, there is the superior Python process (PID 49753) which is parent to the sub-processes, but there is also a `bash` which is parent to that in an analogous way.

Comment: Thank you :) I guess it would be better to actually do some converts and check in `top` if there are 4-5 of them or just 1, I think. I am really newb when it comes to processes and OS stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Short & direct: yes you are running multiple `convert` process on multiple cores.

Longer & slightly indirect: I wouldn't call it "multicore programming", even if it actually is, because that wording usually means running multiple threads of your program on multiple cores, and you're not doing that (at least in CPython, python threads are subject to the GIL and cannot actually run at the same time on multiple cores). Also you don't need to parallelize your python code because that's not your bottleneck (you are spending your time in `convert`, not in python code)

If you only want to parallelize `convert`, you don't even need any threading or other fancy stuff in your python code.

The python script could just be serialized and loop through the photos, spawning new convert processes until you reach the number you like. Then just sit waiting for one of them to finish and spawn a new one; repeat as needed for all your photos.

(but I do agree that threads are more natural and elegant code than that sort of wait-for-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code. You don't need multiple Python processes if the work is done in subprocesses. You could use `multiprocessing.Pool` to limit the number of concurrent subprocesses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp # use threads
from random import randrange
from subprocess import check_call
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def info(msg, _print_lock=mp.Lock()): # a poor man's logging.info()
    with _print_lock: # avoid garbled output
        print("%s\t%s" % (mp.current_process().name, msg))

def work(sec):
    try: # wrap in try/except to avoid premature exit
        info("Sleeping for %d seconds" % (sec,))
        start = timer()
        check_call(["sleep", str(sec)])
    except Exception as e: # error
        return sec, timer() - start, e
    else: # success
        return sec, timer() - start, None

def main():
    work_items = (randrange(1, 5) for i in range(20)) # you can use generator
    pool = mp.Pool(5) # pool of worker threads
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(work, work_items):
        info("expected %s, got %s, error %s" % result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

```
Thread-2    Sleeping for 3 seconds
Thread-4    Sleeping for 4 seconds
Thread-3    Sleeping for 3 seconds
Thread-5    Sleeping for 2 seconds
Thread-1    Sleeping for 1 seconds
Thread-1    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 1, got 1.00222706795, error None
Thread-5    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.00276088715, error None
Thread-2    Sleeping for 1 seconds
MainThread  expected 3, got 3.00330615044, error None
Thread-1    Sleeping for 3 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.00289702415, error None
Thread-4    Sleeping for 1 seconds
Thread-3    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 4, got 4.00349998474, error None
MainThread  expected 3, got 4.00295114517, error None
Thread-2    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 1, got 1.00295495987, error None
Thread-5    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.0029540062, error None
Thread-4    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 1, got 1.00314211845, error None
Thread-3    Sleeping for 4 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.00298595428, error None
Thread-2    Sleeping for 2 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.00294113159, error None
Thread-5    Sleeping for 1 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.00287604332, error None
Thread-1    Sleeping for 4 seconds
MainThread  expected 3, got 3.00323104858, error None
Thread-4    Sleeping for 3 seconds
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.00339794159, error None
Thread-5    Sleeping for 1 seconds
MainThread  expected 1, got 1.00312304497, error None
MainThread  expected 2, got 2.0027179718, error None
MainThread  expected 1, got 1.00284385681, error None
MainThread  expected 4, got 4.00334811211, error None
MainThread  expected 3, got 3.00306892395, error None
MainThread  expected 4, got 4.00330901146, error None
```